# On Windows, using C++, is there a way to tell an application to safely exit?

Tags: winapi, process

Right now, I'm using:

```
TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, 0)
```

... but this doesn't allow the application to clean up.

Our application has a wndProc function, but when I send WM_CLOSE...

```
PostThreadMessage(pi.dwThreadId, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
```

The function doesn't seem to be getting the message.

```
pi is of type: PROCESS_INFORMATION
```

Comment: Try using WM_QUIT instead of WM_CLOSE

Comment: Paul: You shouldn't be sending WM_QUIT, it's done by PostQuitMessage(...) and is not associated with a window, hence not received by the WindProc.

Comment: The reason your window isn't getting the WM_CLOSE is because PostThreadMessage() sets hwnd=NULL, i.e. the message is not sent to a particular window. SendMessage, as Indeera suggests, should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find your window handle (hWnd)

and call SendMessage(hWnd,WM_CLOSE,0,0);